Android: Two launcher icon for two different Acitvities
What is correct method to create two launcher icons for towo activities? I tried it like this:
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".PreviewActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="Preview">

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

But the second activity runs only if there is not launched first one. If first one is launched and I tap on PreviewActivity icon it show SettingsActivity not PreviewActivity as it should. I tried many things like set priority, different order, launchmode and so..
How to do it?

Obviously, none of these two activities has an icon ...
android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_01"
android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_02"

When using android:launchMode=”singleTop”, the second click won't start another activity, but will ultimately end up in method onNewIntent(). When launching the activity from code, there's also Intent flags which one can pass, in order to change the behavior; most also exist in XML.
The problem may be android:taskAffinity, because unless specifying two different affinity names, it is being assumed that all activities belong to the same affinity ...
